# Is the bounty system effective?

Tags: discussion, bounties, statistics

For years, people have been able to spend their hard-earned imaginary Internet points to add "bounties" to questions in order to attract more attention to them. (Because, really, "attention" is the only thing that you can be reasonably sure a bounty will give you.)

But does this extra attention translate into better results?

Granted, any individual question may not be really answerable or is still boring even with the extra carrot. And a question might be so interesting that it would have gotten a ton of (good) answers even without the bounty.

Do questions that have bounties get more/better answers—in aggregate—than questions that never had a bounty? Does this vary by site? If so, do bounties seem more effective at a certain site "size"?

Or is it really just a wash, and that all anyone *ever* gets for their bounty is extra attention?

Comment: I thought bounties were about getting *attention*. That certainly works. Getting good answers is a nice result of that attention, provided the question is actually answerable and of reasonable quality.

Comment: @Martijn: Yes, granted, but one hopes that increased attention will, generally, result in more and/or better answers.

Comment: _Scott Pilgrim vs the World_ had a lot of hype for it. But it didn't smash the box office. Bounties are marketing campaigns. On turds, or ambergris.

Comment: Trying to estimate the effectiveness of bounties from the available observational data is hopeless. Questions that get bounties are not representative of questions in general. One would need a controlled experiment: set bounties on randomly chosen unanswered questions, and select a control group as well.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146638/do-bounties-improve-overall-quality-of-the-posts

Comment: @Thursday: Well, I wasn't suggesting double-blind trials or anything. I guess I was just hoping that someone with a more statistical bent (than me) might look at the Data Explorer with some well-crafted queries.

Comment: @Thursday Try doing that on the small sites. I'm not sure you could even do that on mid-sized sites.

Comment: [Yes, it does.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6804101/2915)

Comment: @AdamDavis Well, when you drop 2000 rep like it's free ... just saying.

Comment: I recently got my first bounty. I was the only answer and had +/-0. So it's not garunteed to work.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The bounty system does bring more views to bountied questions. On average, Stack Overflow questions get 1455 views. Bountied questions average 2631. It stands to reason that the more people who *see* a question, the better the odds it will get a quality answer.

To test that, I divided all answers into three groups:

1. All answers whether their question has been bountied or not (the control),
2. Answers that arrived before the bounty (`before`), and
3. Answers that arrived after the bounty (`after`).

Since questions can have multiple bounties, an answer might belong to all three groups. A slightly cleaner test would only look at questions with just one bounty.

Score is our usual method of determining quality. The [query is based on public data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/221383/does-the-bounty-system-work) and I've included deleted posts.

| group | N | avg_score | bountied_rate | accepted_rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| before | 112270 | 18.8 | 0.122 | 0.123 |
| after | 388660 | 2.9 | 0.259 | 0.243 |
| control | 26548476 | 2.3 | 0.004 | 0.306 |

Despite the extra attention, answers posted after the bounty are barely better scored than answers in general. Existing answers get most of the voting benefit of being featured. It seems entirely possible that this is a result of the [reward existing answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116072/1438) bounty reason. But new answers are more than twice as likely (26%) to receive a bounty as existing answers (12%).

The odds an answer will be accepted has more to do with the total number of other answers to the question than it's actual quality. So let's look at questions instead:

| group | N | avg_score | avg_max_score | avg_bounties | accept_rate | avg_views |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bounty | 161510 | 2.8 | 9.45 | 1.022 | 0.658 | 4536 |
| control | 14181661 | 1.5 | 3.26 | N/A | 0.572 | 2242 |

Questions that have been bountied get higher scoring answers on average. And the highest scoring answer is also markedly higher on average. But as I mentioned above, that could be a function of the greater number of views. There is an increase in accept rate among questions that have been bountied. The surprising thing is how many questions get multiple bounties:

| bounties | N | answers | avg_score | avg_max_score | accept_rate | avg_views |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 14020151 | 2 | 1.5 | 3.2 | 0.571 | 2214 |
| 1 | 158289 | 3 | 2.7 | 8.3 | 0.659 | 4269 |
| 2 | 2979 | 4.5 | 5.8 | 46.1 | 0.574 | 14550 |
| 3 | 182 | 7 | 12.9 | 189 | 0.555 | 48050 |
| 4 | 35 | 10.5 | 13.5 | 166.5 | 0.714 | 72940 |
| 5 | 15 | 6.1 | 7.6 | 25.6 | 0.467 | 5346 |
| 6 | 4 | 12 | 30.8 | 417.5 | 0.25 | 127626 |
| 7 | 3 | 14.7 | 36.8 | 392.3 | 1 | 96343 |
| 10 | 1 | 5 | 63.8 | 170 | 1 | 46912 |
| 13 | 1 | 40 | 28.4 | 430 | 1 | 67442 |
| 14 | 1 | 97 | 444.2 | 26940 | 1 | 1135600 |

I venture to guess that a question really isn't getting better answers after it's first bounty. Every measure of quality except accept rate increases with multiple bounties.

## Summary

Bounties certainly increase attention (as designed). There is some indication that a single bounty also increases answer quality, but multiple bounties probably don't increase anything but attention. I'm only looking at Stack Overflow, but spot checks other sites show similar results.

Comment: I should raise a bounty on your answer !

Comment: When the author goes back to look at a question, the view count goes up.  Questions with bounties are questions people care about. I'd bet a significant part of those extra views are people checking on their own questions (yes you do get notified, but people check anyway).

Comment: @SteveWash: Our viewcounter is a bit more sophisticated than that. It tries to avoid counting the same person more than once. In any case, it's unlikely a single person would push up a question by 1000 or more views.

Comment: Is it?  I have a bounty on a question right now that's had a total of 32 views. If I leave the page and go back, it tells me I have 33 views. I've done that four times now, and the total has increased by 1 each time.  Not likely its getting new views from other users since its been up for days with little traffic.  And with only 36(now) views, it doesn't seem the increased "exposure" is working, either.

Comment: *"It stands to reason that the more people who see a question, the better the odds it will get a quality answer."* That's not a great argument at all -- a thousand people who don't answer, is no better than 10 that don't. A better judge is to see how many Bountied questions have accepted answers, which is something explored here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320145/199700

Answer (score 5):

Bounties gain attention in their own way on each SE site. Each SE site is a culture of it's own, sometimes with overlap into other SE sites, and sometimes with hardly any overlap at all.

I have offered bounties on a few sites with mixed results:

- On Christianity.SE I have offered a bounty to reward an already existing answer that was quite superb. [I earned this one.](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/18465/what-is-the-origin-of-the-idea-that-michael-is-jesus) I have seen, many times, a bounty bring in equally superb answers as many as 100 days after the question was asked.
- On MSE, when it was MSO, actually, [I offered a bounty on a feature request that was not my question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136224/is-it-possible-to-have-site-specific-badges) to get the SE staff to notice it. It received no further attention from anyone except a few more upvotes and a worthless answer that basically said "yep, me too," which three people upvoted for some reason.
- I just offered a bounty on SU for a question that went three weeks with no activity at all. We will see.

On the bigger sites, the quality of interaction seems to decline the bigger it gets. They are a victim of their own success. Hence, I don't think the bounties are too effective for those sites.

On the mid-sized sites, the bounties seem to work very well. There is a high possibility that a regular user can answer very well, but for the few upvotes they might get, they are not really willing to put in the time. The promise of a bounty gives them that extra push.

I have no experience with the small sites, but I suspect the bounties are hit and miss, mostly because there is actually a good chance that none of the regular users can provide a good answer.

See that your only experience is on SO and MSE, I can understand you frustrations.

Here's some examples:

- On C.SE, the bounty made most of those answers; the OP didn't award any of them for some reason: [Why does God command us to have children?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/18500/why-does-god-command-us-to-have-children/18796#18796) I personally think most of those answers are pretty good. [This question's current bounty](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/14109/why-did-protestants-abandon-liturgy-of-the-hours) brought in three answers so far, of which, [one](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/32419/3961) is pretty good. [This question's bounty](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/18258/what-are-typical-christian-responses-to-the-grand-inquisitor) has brought in [one](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/32468/3961) answer so far, that at least looks extensive, but I can't comment on quality/factuality; it has no up or down votes.
- On MSE I found my reposting of this, after the bounty on the other did exactly nothing. Still nothing on the reposting: [Revisit favorite answers feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221729/revisit-favorite-answers-feature-request)
- This is my question on SU with the current bounty: [Is is possible to get a virtual disc drive to mount over usb to another machine's motherboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/792966/is-is-possible-to-get-a-virtual-disc-drive-to-mount-over-usb-to-another-machine)

Comment: You did not offer a bounty on the SU question, or it would be recorded in the [post history](http://superuser.com/posts/734939/revisions). This is the history of [C.SE question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/posts/18500/revisions). I don't see a bounty on your [MSE question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/221729/revisions) either...

Comment: The MSE question was not the one I bountied. I put the bounty on a question that was not mine, specifically to get an answer from SE staff. I cannot find that question, and I'm not sure if it is on MSE or MSO. The result is that it did not get any useful attention. I'm not even 100% sure if the question I bountied was on the same subject. The point is that I resorted to reposting instead of a bounty because the bounty did nothing.

Comment: @Thursday I've updated. One of my SU posts has a current bounty on it right now.

Comment: The question you bountied on MSE is [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/212646/fredsbend?tab=bounties&sort=offered).

Comment: @Thursday Thanks. I've updated again. My search voodoo is off today, I guess. Just curious, are you always "Thursday" or does your name change daily along with the weekly calendars?

Comment: Sadly, display name can be changed only once in 30 days. So, my name is accurate 1/7 of the time.  Maybe I should switch from days of the week to months? For now, I have [reasons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_Who_Was_Thursday) to like the present name.

Comment: @Thursday Cool. There's a lot of Chesterton fans on C.SE.

Answer (score 2):

Personally as an answerer, I do get a hit off the dopamine from a bounty - hightened by that delayed gratification and risk while waiting for the bounty to finish. When I put in a good answer but it doesnt get enough votes to score the bounty I am crushed (briefly).

I have several tags where I have expertise but I'll only look at bountied questions.  It's an effective way for me to avoid getting too sucked in to SO.

BTW it's so ironic that the OP gave a bounty for the best answer ...